# C function float argument takes different value inside the function

Tags: c, function

I am sure I'm missing something obvious here but just can't figure out what it is. In [my repository](https://github.com/ryu577/base/tree/master/numerical/c/NumericalRecipiesCode/src/ch5),  I have a file called ddpoly_2.c which contains a function called "ddpoly2". I call this function from the main function in tst5.c. If you look at the code in tst5_2.c, I am assigning to x a value of 2, immediately printing it and then passing it to "ddpoly2" as the third argument (which is as per what the calling pattern should be like as far as I can tell). I then immediately print x from within the function "ddpoly2". What I see is the following:

```
x outside: 2.000000
x inside : 0.000000
nc: 2
nd: 3
```

You can see that x was 2.000000 just before the function was called but it became 0.0000000 once inside the function. I must be missing something overtly obvious here but can't figure out what it is.

P.S. I compile the code using the makefile in the same directory.

EDIT: Including relevant parts of code here.

Calling the function in tst5_2.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//Used to determine which section gets its results printed.

    float c[] = {1,1,1,0,0};
    int nc = 2;
    float x = 2.0;
    float pd[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int nd = 3;
    printf("x outside: %f\n",x);
    ddpoly2(c,nc,x,pd,nd);      
}
```

printing it inside the function ddpoly2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ddpoly2(float c[], int nc, float x, float pd[], int nd)
{
    int nnd, j, i;
    float cnst = 1.0;
    printf("x inside : %f\n",x);
    printf("nc: %d\n",nc);
    printf("nd: %d\n",nd);
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual piece of code you are referring to in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you also please show the actual *call* to the function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Added - sorry for missing that.

Comment: You have to create a **new** file, build your MCVE inside, check it gives the same error as in your project (thus, it must compile and link) and then post it. That is what we call a MCVE.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I can't find the point where you declare your `ddpoly` function. How does your project even compile?

Comment: Are `ddpoly` and `main` defined in separate source files? If yes, recompile everything. Because, if they are in separate files, it is possible that: 1) at some point you created `ddpoly` function with another list of arguments; 2) you compiled source code with `ddpoly` into object file; 3) you modified definition/declaration of `ddpoly` but didn't recompile its source file; 4) you compiled main source file; 5) you linked ddpoly object file (which uses old declaration) with new main object file.

Comment: @jdarthenay: Created new files for everything (edited question as well) and still see the repro.

Comment: @gudok: Deleted all .o files, created new versions of the tst5.c and ddpoly.c files, rebuilt using make and still see the repro.

Comment: do you get any compiler warnings? like implicit declaration of ddpoly2? I don't see where `main` is given the prototype for `ddpoly2`.

Comment: I am looking at `tst5_2.c`. It uses `ddpoly` which must be declared either in `nrutils.h` or `fileio.h` or in their descendants in order to compile. But I do not see any declaration there...

Comment: Thanks @gudock. I added void ddpoly2(float x); to the top of the tst5_2.c file (I had in the meantime trimmed the minimal repro still further) and now the outside and inside values of x match up. Still, it is concerning that the other int variables nc and nd got the correct values even though I didn't add the method signature and only x which was a float was getting the wrong value. Anyway, thanks for solving the problem. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling a function without a prototype. This is illegal since 1999 but your compiler is helpful and allows this as a compatibility with old C standards.

The C standard says:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double.

The correct solution is to:

1. Always have correct function prototypes.
2. Always enable all warnings in compilation and treat them as errors.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` should always be on your command line.

Comment: I heard somewhere that programming in C is like swordfighting and ice skating at the same time. I now see why.